# Cant get Maps featureFeed to work

Tags: google-api-java-client

I am having a real issue retrieving map features from the features feed through the new java api on Android.
Although i can get a featrureFeed containing an id and title (from a specific MapFeed), as soon as i add in FeatureContent to the request (for getting the placemark details)  FeatureFeed.executeGet() returns with a '400 bad request' error.
Am i doing something wrong, or is there actually an error with this at the moment?
Below is some of my code - any information would be greatly appreciated as i've been banging my head against this for 3 days! (i've tried "kml:placemark", "atom:placemark" and "placemark" in the FeatureContent class)

```
public class FeatureFeed { 
    @Key("atom:id") 
    public String id; 
    @Key("atom:title") 
    public String title; 
    @Key("atom:entry") 
    public List features;
```

```
public List<FeatureEntry> maps = new ArrayList<FeatureEntry>();

public static FeatureFeed executeGet( HttpTransport transport,
                BuildMapsUrl url) throws IOException {
 url.fields = GData.getFieldsFor(FeatureFeed.class);
 AtomParser parser = new AtomParser();
 parser.namespaceDictionary = Namespace.FEED_NAMESPACE_DICTIONARY;
 transport.addParser(parser);
 HttpRequest request = transport.buildGetRequest();
 request.url = url;
 return (FeatureFeed) RedirectHandler.
                  execute(request).parseAs(FeatureFeed.class);
}
```

}

public class FeatureEntry implements Cloneable {
 @Key("atom:id")
 public String id;
 @Key("atom:title")
 public String title;
 @Key("atom:content")
 public FeatureContent content;

public FeatureEntry() {
  // required
 }
 public FeatureEntry(String title, FeatureContent content) {
  this.title = title;
  this.content = content;
 }
}

public class FeatureContent implements Cloneable {

@Key("@type")
 public String contentType = "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml";

@Key ("kml:Placemark") // adding this always fails with Bad Request
 public FeaturePlaceMark placemark; // adding this always fails with Bad Request

public FeatureContent() {
  //required
 }

public FeatureContent(FeaturePlaceMark placemark) {
  this.placemark = placemark;
 }
}

FEED_NAMESPACE_DICTIONARY.namespaceAliasToUriMap; 
                 feedMap.put("", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
                 feedMap.put("kml", "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"); 
                 feedMap.put("atom", "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom");
                 feedMap.put("exif", "http://schemas.google.com/photos/exif/2007"); 
                 feedMap.put("gd", "http://schemas.google.com/g/2005");
                 feedMap.put("gm", "http://schemas.google.com/g/2008#mapfeature");
                 feedMap.put("geo", "http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#"); 
                 feedMap.put("georss", "http://www.georss.org/georss"); 
                 feedMap.put("gml", "http://www.opengis.net/gml"); 
                 feedMap.put("gphoto", "http://schemas.google.com/photos/2007"); 
                 feedMap.put("media", "http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"); 
                 feedMap.put("openSearch", "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"); 
                 feedMap.put("xml", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace");

Answer (score 0):

I have been there too...
And when I delete this sentence `url.fields = GData.getFieldsFor(FeatureFeed.class);`,the program runs well,weird but effective. You can try it out.